# Using common classes with withStyles and material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am using React with TypeScript and Material UI. So I have the the following layout

```
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
     <My Component/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
```

And then in my component I have something similar to

```
let styles: any = ({ palette }: any) => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: 10
  }
});

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

What would be the preferred way to go if I want to share the `root` class among multiple components? Can I extend Material UI theme when I am creating it using `createMuiTheme`?

Any advise will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I define my custom theme in Material-ui

```
const Theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#40bbbf',
      main: '#032B43',
      dark: '#0b777b',
    },
  },
  customCommonClass: {
    textAlign: center,
  },
})

Theme.overrides = {
  MuiListItemIcon: {
    root: {
      marginRight: 0,
    },
  },
  MuiListItem: {
    dense: {
      paddingTop: '4px',
      paddingBottom: '4px',
    },
  },
}
```

There are 3 parts within this creation:

1. the first I will define some defaults of my theme (for the fontSize, and palette color as an example)
2. The second I create some global class `customCommonClass` that I can use in all styled components down the road (your question)
3. I override some class of the material ui components.

hope this can help

Comment: Well I am not sure that the above approach will work with the typescript deffinitions

Comment: not a big expert in typescript. You will probably need to make a few adjustments to type the variables but I am pretty sure this is the pattern you can use to define a Global theme